# Getting different results from deeplearning4j and word2vec

Tags: word2vec

I trained a word embedding model using Google's word2vec. The output is a file that contains a word and its vector.

I loaded this trained model in deeplearing4j.

```
    WordVectors vec = WordVectorSerializer.loadTxtVectors(new File("vector.txt"));
    Collection<String> lst = vec.wordsNearest("someWord", 10);
```

But the two lists of similar words obtained from deeplearing4j's package and word2vec's distance function are totally different although I used the same vector file.

Does anyone have a good understanding on how things work in deeplaring4j and where these differences are coming from?

Comment: We support the DL4J community on Gitter: gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Comment: Did you use the same parameters while training both the models?

Answer (score 1):

Are the lists similar at all? Does either set seem more reasonable as similar words?

By my understanding, the lists should match almost exactly - they should be implementing the same calculation on the same input vectors. If they don't, and especially if the original word2vec.c similar-list looks more reasonable, then I would suspect a bug in DL4J.

Looking at the method doing the calculation – https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/f943ea879ab362f66b57b00754b71fb2ff3677a1/deeplearning4j-scaleout/deeplearning4j-nlp/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/models/embeddings/wordvectors/WordVectorsImpl.java#L385 :

- the code for the `if (lookupTable() instanceof InMemoryLookupTable) {...}` branch may be correct – I'm not familiar with the nd4j API – but almost seems too ornate for the calculation of ranked cosine-similarity values;
- the fallback case that follows does not appear to use unit-vector normalized vector values (as would be usual) – it uses `getWordVectorMatrix()` instead of `getWordVectorMatrixNormalized()`

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons why you are getting different vectors from different implementations (and hence difference in the similar words). I can mention a few

- random initialisation of vectors
- negative sampling
- threading

If your number of documents (training data) >> number of unique words (vocabulary size), the vectors for the words will stabilise after few iterations and you can find some of the most similar words from the two, similar.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But in my case, I used the same vector trained from one method. I was only trying to load the vector result trained in word2vec model in deeplaring4j.