# Word2Vec, most_similar(word1) returns same output on different runs

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm doing a small experiment where I have 2000 tweets as my input document. I train word2vec on this input tweets and then find the top 10 most similar words to a particular word - `w1`.

My concern is if I run word2vec 10 times (with same parameters) and inspect the top 10 most similar words to `w1`, gives me the same set of words (weights are also the same).

Now AFAIK word2vec initializes random weights at the beginning so why it's giving me the same output at different runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `seed` of gensim's word2vec is set to 1 as described in [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec). For different outputs, try varying the seed variable

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec

sentences = ['a quick brown fox jumps over a dog'.split()]
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1, size=5, seed=1)
print model['fox']

Out: array([ 0.0629408 ,  0.07386301, -0.00788937, -0.09287976,  0.05859811], dtype=float32)

model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1, size=5, seed=2)
print model['fox']

Out: array([-0.05617044,  0.00294411, -0.09557492,  0.02923537, -0.08322554], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: but when i change the order of the tweets in the input document, i get different weights. This could happen as the contexts of first and last words would change depending on the order. But gensim documentation says - "window is the maximum distance between the current and predicted word within a sentence.", meaning context is limited to a sentence (tweet here). why does it change then when i change the order?

Comment: Weights are initialized for the vocabulary randomly. If order of the tweets are different, its very likely the order of words in the vocabulary is different, and hence initialization of word vectors will be different in two cases

Comment: Sources of randomness are of course not limited to this only, some of the other sources of randomness are in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749330/getting-different-results-from-deeplearning4j-and-word2vec/32804468#32804468

Comment: "Weights are initialized for the vocabulary randomly.", im using the same seed value so that's not a possibility. if this is the case, then how would i get the same vectors when i run word2vec twice (or more) on the same input with same parameters?

Comment: Since order of tweets are different so order of words in your vocabulary will be different. Say if your vocab earlier was ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], and now it is ['b', 'c', 'a', 'd'], even if you use the same seed, words will be initialized differently

Comment: just one more thing, what did you mean by "words will be initialized" and how does that happen?

Comment: I recommend you reading http://www-personal.umich.edu/~ronxin/pdf/w2vexp.pdf. In word2vec, you are learning word-vectors by a gradient descent algorithm. For this, you need to initialize your word-vectors with some random values and improve on those values based on gradients over the error function

Comment: sorry for keep bugging you but in my mind it's still not really clear. "For this, you need to..", isn't that the value of the seed in the algorithm? also if wor2vec not going to look at words from nearby sentences when determining the context, how does the order of words in the vocabulary really matter? how could that be the reason? ( i hv looked at that paper already thanks tho)